# Decomposition of $2+2^2+2^{2^2}+2^{2^{2^2}}+2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's a little question about number theory :
Remark that we have :
$$2+2^2=2*3$$
$$2+2^2+2^{2^2}=2*11$$
$$2+2^2+2^{2^2}+2^{2^{2^2}}=2*32779$$
Do we have :
$$2+2^2+2^{2^2}+2^{2^{2^2}}+2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}=2*p\quad?$$
Where $p$ is a prime number .

Thanks a lot for your comment or answer .

Comment: @martinr it can’t be divisible by $4$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Seems that I made a typo. Now I get  $2, 3, 2819$ as the lowest prime factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.$$2+2^2+2^{2^2}+2^{2^{2^2}}+2^{2^{2^{2^2}}} \equiv 2 + 1 + 1 +1 + 1 \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$ Because $2^{2n}\equiv (-1)^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{3}$